# Animated GIF problem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have added above code in my WPF from which include animated GIF image, the problem is whenever form load I don't find any of the Image displayed on form, any suggestions ???

```
<Image Name="imgScan"  Source="Images\Pre_Scan_RealImage.gif" />
```

I even tried Image element shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond UserControl [here](http://www.solidrockstable.com/blogs/PragmaticTSQL/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37) for showing Animated GIFs, and guess what work just works as simple as Image control.

And thank you all

Here's the [same article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120413012735/http://www.solidrockstable.com/blogs/PragmaticTSQL/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37) (web post captured by the Wayback Machine)

Comment: The link is dead, so this answer is now useless.  Can you give any details?

Answer (score 11):

**Use XAML below**

```
<MediaElement Height="30" Width="30" LoadedBehavior="Play" Source="Images\loading.gif" />
```

**Set properties of loading.gif**

1. **BuildAction** : None
2. **Copy to Output Directory** : Copy always

It should work.

Answer (score 6):

WPF at the moment doesn't natively support animated GIFs.

You can get around it by [hosting the image in a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf).

EDIT : Also checkout [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/93d50a97-0d8d-4b18-992e-cd3200693337) thread for a bit more info.

Answer (score 2):

> I even tried Image element shown above

And did it work or not?  ;)

The `MediaElement` does not yet support pack URIs. That means you'll need to include the GIF as an external file, not a resource. That may be your problem, but you'll need to provide more info if not.