# Problem with animated GIF in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animated-gif

I try to show animated GIFs in WPF application using custom classes found at [How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf)
First I used AnimatedImage class, after that - GifImage class. Both classes failed during animation initialization (while resoving Uri to the GIF file, saved as app. resource, its "Build action" = resource).

The result of second attempts was shown in the picture at this link: http://i.piccy.info/i5/47/02/490247/2.png

Sorry for link, but StackOverflow engine says, that I must have at least 10 reputation points in order to use pictures.

What is the error?

Comment: archive with the exmaple VS2010 project: http://rapidshare.com/files/419195171/WpfApplication2.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the image isn't specified correctly.

When using resource files packed into the assembly all you need to provide is the path to the image, without /component or anything else. You can try both with and without a leading slash, I forget what the difference is.

If you want to specify the absolute URI, you'll need the entire PackURI:

```
pack://application:,,,/MyProgram;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.ext
```

You can find more details about the pack URIs in the quite comprehensive [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) dedicated to them.