# Why GifBitmapDecoder play incomplete gif

Tags: .net, wpf, gif

I want to play a gif image using GifBitmapDecoder and Int32Animation, but I found some gif is incomplete when they were played.

Here is my gif:

[image]

And here is my test code:

```
GifBitmapDecoder _gifDecoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(
            new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Expression/f006.gif"), 
            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

foreach (BitmapFrame bf in _gifDecoder.Frames)
{
     Image i = new Image { Source = bf };
     wp.Children.Add(i);
}
```

Xaml:

```
<WrapPanel Name="wp" ItemHeight="40" ItemWidth="40"/>
```

The result:

[image]

So could you tell me what's wrong, since I have search for it two days and find nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Individual GIF frames might be just portions of an image at any arbitrary X,Y-coordinate.

For properly placing a frame in the image, you will need the X,Y-coordinate of the frame.
Read this post about how to get this information: [Reading Metadata property of GifBitmapDecoder...why is it null?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589103/2819245)

Then to get a complete image you must merge the frame with the previous frame(s), until a complete image is being obtained. However, assuming that your real "GIF player" just draws the animation frames one on top of another (instead of putting them side-by-side in a StackPanel), this would happen automagically...