# How do you pull the XY Coordinates of a partial GIF frame in C#.net

Tags: .net, animated-gif

In reference to the thread, [Why GifBitmapDecoder play incomplete gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992993/why-gifbitmapdecoder-play-incomplete-gif).

How do you go about pulling the X,Y-coordinate information for each partial GIF frame in order to build a complete image for each frame? Below is the code I currently have. I am just missing how to pull the location of the partial GIF frame so I can place it properly on the stack.

```
GifBitmapDecoder gif_decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(
    this.stream, 
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, 
    BitmapCacheOption.None
);

Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(
    this.bmp_img_frames[0].PixelWidth, 
    this.bmp_img_frames[0].PixelHeight, 
    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb
);

//Make background transparent
bmPhoto.MakeTransparent();

//Set X and Y DPI
bmPhoto.SetResolution(72, 72);

for (int i = 0; i < gif_decoder.Frames.Count(); i++) 
{
    //create a new graphics object from our image and set properties
    Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
    //Set Graphics Properties
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

    //now do the crop
    grPhoto.DrawImage(
        this.build_img(gif_decoder.Frames[i]), 
        new Rectangle(
            0, 
            0, 
            gif_decoder.Frames[i].PixelWidth,
            gif_decoder.Frames[i].PixelHeight
        ), 
        0, 
        0, 
        gif_decoder.Frames[i].PixelWidth, 
        gif_decoder.Frames[i].PixelHeight, 
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to work this. The solution is below. Instead of building an entire image from each frame, I used the Image loaded as a System.Drawing.Image object and drew that into a fresh Bitmap.

```
GifBitmapDecoder gif_decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(
    this.stream, 
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, 
    BitmapCacheOption.None
);

Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(
    this.bmp_img_frames[0].PixelWidth, 
    this.bmp_img_frames[0].PixelHeight, 
    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb
);

List<Image> image_frames = new List<Image>();

//Make background transparent
bmPhoto.MakeTransparent();

//Set X and Y DPI
bmPhoto.SetResolution(72, 72);

MemoryStream[] streams = new MemoryStream[gif_decoder.Frames.Count()];

using(Image frame = Image.FromStream(this.stream)) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gif_decoder.Frames.Count(); i++) 
    {
        streams[i] = new MemoryStream();
        frame.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);

        using(Bitmap bmp_img = new Bitmap(frame.Width, frame.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
        {
            bmp_img.MakeTransparent();
            bmp_img.SetResolution(72, 72);

            using(Graphics graphic_img = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_img))
            {
                //Set Graphics Properties
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

                graphic_img.DrawImage(frame, new Rectangle(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height), 0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height, GraphicUnit.Pixel);
            }
            bmp_img.Save(streams[i], ImageFormat.Gif);
        }
        streams[i].Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image_frames.add(Image.FromStream(streams[i]));
    }
}
```