# C# Windows Forms Animated Emoticons

Tags: c#, winforms, chat

So, i have tossed around a few ideas, and would like to add animated emoticons to my chat app.  Currently, in AutoIT, i use an HTML page to display those when a user clicks on a static image.  That, obviously, isn't ideal.

Is there a way to display all of my animated GIF's (emoticons) either via an ImageList and still have them animated say inside of a listview? ComboBox?

What would be the best way to do emoticons inside of Windows Forms (displaying)?

Comment: No resolution found to date on this issue, unfortunately; So, instead, i'll just replace random smilies in chat automatically.  I'm not going to switch to WPF for just this one functionality; nor will i embed WPF into this WinForms, for that one small capability, seems kinda silly to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to turn to WPF rather than forms: [How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf)

(following comments I am adding this link to the answer as well)

If you want to use WPF in a forms enviroment, use the ElementHost tag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.INTEGRATION.CHILDCHANGEDEVENTARGS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true

Comment: Um... I happen to be working on a desktop application deployed using ClickOnce, and the UI is written entirely in WPF. So... is something else limiting you? (Or are you confusing WPF with Silverlight...?)

Comment: @user674311 what @djacobson is saying is that ClickOnce is not a reason to avoid WPF. Even if you want to stay "mostly" in the forms world you can use the "ElementHost" control (winforms) to host a WPF element (or elements) so that you can get the best of both worlds. To learn more about this option start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=VS.90).aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.INTEGRATION.CHILDCHANGEDEVENTARGS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-".NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5");k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true.

Comment: whoops. gave you the wrong link.. the right one is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.INTEGRATION.CHILDCHANGEDEVENTARGS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true