# Playing animation in WPF - Supported image format?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I want to include an animation in my windows WPF/C# application, it's a loading animation (but more complicated than just a spinner).

I originally thought I would use a GIF, I thought there would be some built-in support for playing them, but **[apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf)**.

**Does WPF have any built-in support for any animation format?**

**Or should I just go with the method in the above link?**

My animation includes transparency and varied opacity settings.

I have made the animation myself so I can convert it to whichever format is best.

Comment: maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf

Comment: I have gone with the PictureBox method (as described in the link in my question) for now, it's adequate but doesn't answer my question. It also required some sacrifice to my UI, because `WindowsFormsHost` doesn't work with `AllowsTransparency`.

Comment: I Would still appreciate it if someone new of a WPF way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [this simple library](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/) in my recent WPF project. Take a look. Maybe it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, this one is great. It's the only one that I could get working.