# Load a series of images that have the effect of a movement WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, load

I wanted to know how I could make a button to load a window that allows me to upload 3 images, so giving the impression of a gif.

If I do a single project everything is fine, but when I do I associate a button does not work for me. 
Why is that? 
Can someone help me understand?

This code XAML:

```
<Image Name="ConnectionImage" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Name="DoubleAnimation_ConnectionTest" Storyboard.TargetName="ConnectionImage" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="200" To="200" 
                                             Duration="0:0:1.0"  Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
```

while the code of image is:

```
    int ctr = 1;
    private void DoubleAnimation_Completed (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowImage();
        DoubleAnimation_ConnectionTest.BeginAnimation(Image.WidthProperty, DoubleAnimation_ConnectionTest);
    }

    private void ShowImage()
    {
        string filename = "Images/Connection" + ctr + ".jpg";
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
        image.EndInit();
        ConnectionImage.Source = image;

        ctr++;

        if (ctr > 3)
        {
            ctr = 1;
        }
    }
```

and button:

```
 private void Button_Test_DB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window_Test Test_DB = new Window_Test();
            Test_DB.Show();

        }
```

Comment: "does not work for me" is not really a useful problem description. Please be more specific about that. And a note: using an animation's Completed event for cyclic execution of some code looks really strange. Why not just use a DispatcherTimer?

Comment: If I do a project with only the animation in a window then it works, otherwise button retrieved from the window, I get out a window empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is entirely possible using C#. You can use the [`FrameDimension` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.framedimension(v=vs.110).aspx) to help you. Unfortunately, I can't close this question for being a duplicate because there are no accepted answers to these posts... instead, I can only recommend that you see the answers to the [How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf) and [Animating Gif in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694640/animating-gif-in-wpf) questions here on Stack Overflow.

Additionally, you could also see the [The Code - An Animated GIF Class](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif2.php) page from the Visual C# Kicks website.

Comment: Thanks, but it really is not a gif, but a series of animated images that make the design because they are in sequence.