# Embed GIF image doesn't animate in WPF in Picture Box,

Tags: wpf, picturebox, resx

I have added Picture Box(win form) in WPF. when I assign pic box embedded gif image from resx file it doesn't animate while image from disk does animate. Any solution? I want embedded image to animate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't out of the box.
Use the [Animated GIF in WPF](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/) component instead.

Comment: Note that some claim you can using `MediaElement` (see Stewbob's link). I tried it myself and it almost worked, but only displayed the first four frames of the GIF I tested with.