# Animating Gif in WPF using MediaElement

Tags: wpf, animated-gif, mediaelement

I'm using the MediaElement to show gif image as shown below.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="imgLoadingImage" 
    MediaEnded="imgLoadingImage_MediaEnded" 
    UnloadedBehavior="Manual"     
    Source="file:\loading.GIF" 
    LoadedBehavior="Play" 
    Stretch="None" 
    Visibility="Visible"/>
```

It works fine but the transparent pixels are shown as black.

Is there anyway we can make it transparent?

Comment: Transparency for GIF images isn’t supported in MediaElement, you can find an alternative appproch from http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/

Comment: but i don't want to use any external libraries and packages.

Answer (score 5):

The `WebBrowser` option won't work with MVVM, however you can apply the animated Gif as it's own transparency mask and then it works:

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Play" Source="{Binding MyGif}" >
    <MediaElement.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyGif}"/>
    </MediaElement.OpacityMask>
</MediaElement>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a work around for this.
Instead of using MediaElement control I've used WebBrowser control which can render GIF image as HTML content

```
    <WebBrowser x:Name="wbImage" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/loading.gif"/>
```

Comment: I'd check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf . Using a `WebBrowser` for this is pretty much overkill.

Comment: Not to mention the memory leaks WebBrowser still has despite plenty of patches from MS where they could have fixed the issue.