# Animation Splash Screen (GIF) does not work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, splash-screen

I create an animation GIF image and added to my project as Splash screen.

When I run my application the splash screen appeared BUT the animation does not work !

Any suggestion?

Comment: WPF SplashScreen supports only static images. If you wish to use dynamic splash screen you have to emulate it with ordinary window. You can design it to be borderless (WindowStyle="None") and place gif image there (look up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf for how to do so)

Comment: But the normal window has a delay on startup

Comment: In my practice the delay is negligible if you keep overhead at minimum, e.g. create splash window at very beginning of Application.Startup handling, have little or no dependencies (minimum third-party libraries, no IoC, all controls/styles are placed in the same assembly... for splash window and content, that is), therefore it is initialized and shown almost immediately

Comment: Maybe this helps too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664221/splash-screen-with-animated-gif-is-not-animating-in-wpf-c-sharp