# Splash Screen with Animated GIF is not animating in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

So here is the situation. I am currently working on a C# WPF Desktop Application and I wanted to add a Splash Screen when starting the program.

But I am not using the SplashScreen class. I am using an additional WPF windows class on top of the app of the same name, and I call that class Splashy.

My splash screen has an animated GIF image that works well when animated on the WebBrowser control of the Splashy class below...

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images/FSIntro.gif" Margin="10,1,0,10">
    <Image.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/FSIntro.gif"/>
    </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

...and the Splashy class itself is initialized as a StartupUri below in the App.XAML.

```
<Application
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         ...  ...
         ... (some text) ...
         ...  ...
         StartupUri="Splashy.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
```

But the problem with that scenario is the **splash screen just hangs** and does not go into the main program itself.

So I tried a different approach. One using code.

And when I implement the following code to the Splash Screen and then implement it to my program to run the splash screen and then display the home screen, the splash screen does what I want to do **but it does not animate** as I would want.

Below is the Splashy class code

```
public partial class Splashy : Window
{
    public Intro()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Outro()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And below is the program's method where the splashScreen is being implemented.

```
public partial class LoginScreen : Window
{
    Splashy splash = new Splashy();

    public LoginScreen()
    {

        splash.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        splash.Outro();

        // home screen 
    }
}
```

Any pointers and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely because you're sleeping the UI thread?

Comment: Programmers typically use a splash screen to cover up the fact that their UI thread is not responsive.  Busy initializing itself.  "Not responsive" includes not getting a GIF animated.  Not something you ought to consider fixing, given that this is pretty hard to do correctly and you probably don't need the splash screen anymore when you do :)  Keep it simple.

Comment: @Ross Chris please mark as correct when you've got a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this instead. Create a `Bootstrapper` class that handles all this logic.

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    SplashScreen Splash = new SplashScreen();
    MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow();

    public void Start()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Splash.Close();
            MainWindow.Show();
            timer.Stop();
        };

        timer.Start();
        Splash.Show();
    }
}
```

Remove the `StartupUri` from `App.xaml` so that your `MainWindow` isn't created first.

```
<Application x:Class="StackOverflow.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

becomes...

```
<Application x:Class="StackOverflow.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow">
```

Then, in the `App.xaml.cs`, override the startup so that it creates a new instance of your `Bootstrapper` class.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
        bootStrapper.Start();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO much, Ralt! I'm sorry for the late reply, but I truly appreciate your help here. This method saved my time and life altogether. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to load a splash screen during the wpf application take long time to loading it, please after you had created your animated windows keep the  App.xaml original form like this:

```
<Application x:Class="StackOverflow.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
     StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

And insert your screen at App.Xaml.cs class in this form:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{   
    public static readonly BootstrapScreen BoostrapScreen = new BootstrapScreen();
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += (sender, e) =>
        {
           
            #region - Splash -
            App.BoostrapScreen.Show();
            #endregion
        };
    }
}
```

Don't forget to close your bootstrapScreen when the MainWindow.xaml will be loaded.