# Media element not support in WPF Page

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, mediaelement

I want to display a progress bar in WPF Page,when it loaded. I used media element to display a gif image. Below code describe what I did.

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication3.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page1" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <MediaElement  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,0,47,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Source="progress.gif" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Name="MP"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>


 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MP.Play();
    }
```

but this progress bar not showing in Page
How can I fix this.
(when I tried with progress bar also, got same problm)

(It works ok in window )

Comment: Have you checked your gif resource? Is it playing well when you open it in web browser, like IE

Comment: yes . even it working properly in windows application also

Comment: what's your os and target framework version

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `WpfAnimatedGif` library to easily display an animated gif using a simple Image element:

[How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf)

Just download the package from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAnimatedGif

And set the `ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource` attached property of the `Image` element:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication3.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page1"
    <Grid>
        <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="progress.gif" />
   </Grid>
</Page>
```