# WPF Displaying an animated gif inside a WPF image using WpfAnimatedGif codeplex library cause exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I am trying to display an animated gif in a WPF image by using [this](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif) library.

I have done a little NET 3.5 WPF test project and it works perfectly, no problems.

Then as I have seen this library works to display an animated gif inside an image, I want to do the same in my real WPF NET 3.5 project.

So in my real project I have a class library which contains a WPF window. This window uses this library (I have referenced this codeplex library in the class library project) to display the animated gif within an WPF image. This WPF window is used in my main WPF application (I add as a reference this class library). In this window I import the namespace as below:

```
xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
```

then I use in my WPF image as below:

```
<Image x:Name="img"                   
       Stretch="None" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
gif:ImageBehavior.AnimateInDesignMode="True"             
gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="/My.XAML;component/Resources/metroProgressBar.gif"/>
```

In design time, in Visual Studio 2008, the animated gif is seen within the image without problems but when I execute the program, it crashes. I have seen that the culprit is this line:

```
xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
```

that is located in the WPF Window within my class library project.

If I remove this line, and obviously the wpf image from the wpf window, my wpf program executes without problems.

The exception raised in the line:

```
xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
```

is the below (sorry this is in spanish):

```
Ocurrió System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  Message="No se puede crear una instancia de 'wMain' en el ensamblado 'MyRealWPFProject, Version=1.5.1.18, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se produjo una excepción en el destino de la invocación.  Error en el archivo de marcado 'MyRealWPFProject;component/wMain.xaml' Línea 1 Posición 9."
  Source="PresentationFramework"
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       en System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message="Se produjo una excepción en el destino de la invocación."
       Source="mscorlib"
       StackTrace:
            en System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            en System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
            en System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
            en System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            en System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            Message="Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."
            Source="WindowsBase"
            StackTrace:
                 en System.Windows.Markup.ReflectionHelper.IsPublicType(Type type)
                 en System.Windows.Markup.XamlTypeMapper.UpdateAttachedPropertyMethdodInfo(BamlAttributeInfoRecord attributeInfo, Boolean isSetter)
                 en System.Windows.Markup.PropertyDefinition.get_AttachedPropertySetter()
                 en System.Windows.Markup.PropertyDefinition.get_PropertyType()
                 en System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadPropertyCustomRecord(BamlPropertyCustomRecord bamlPropertyRecord)
                 en System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
                 en System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
                 en System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
                 en System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
                 en System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
                 en System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
                 en My.Tools.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfSplashScreen.InitializeComponent() en c:\Users\atp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VS2008\My\Tools\My.Tools.XAML\Controls\Windows\WpfSplashScreen.xaml:línea 1
                 en My.Tools.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfSplashScreen..ctor(String waitMessage, String appName, String appVersion) en C:\Users\atp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VS2008\My\Tools\My.Tools.XAML\Controls\Windows\WpfSplashScreen.xaml.cs:línea 23
                 en My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject.ViewModels.wMainViewModel.InicalitzarBackground() en C:\Users\atp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VS2008\My\Apps\WPF\My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject\ViewModels\wMainViewModel.cs:línea 931
                 en My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject.ViewModels.wMainViewModel..ctor(IView view) en C:\Users\atp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VS2008\My\Apps\WPF\My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject\ViewModels\wMainViewModel.cs:línea 779
                 en My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject.wMain..ctor() en C:\Users\atp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VS2008\My\Apps\WPF\My.Apps.WPF.MyRealWPFProject\wMain.xaml.cs:línea 78
            InnerException:
```

I do not understand why it is working in my test project and not in my real project. What am i doing wrong? I do the same.

I have put a breakpoint in the constructor of the wpf window that contains the image with the gif animated and i can reach without problems to the line in the constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Then If i continue using F11, it goes to parse first line of the xaml view:

```
<Window x:Class="My.Tools.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfSplashScreen" ...
```

Then it crashes showing the above exception.

**SOLUTION**:

As swiszcz suggested I have set image in code-behind, just in Window_Loaded:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri("/My.Tools.XAML;component/Resources/metroProgressBar.gif", UriKind.Relative);
        image.EndInit();
        ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);

        // Below it needed to start animation. If not, it is only make visible but animation does not start.
        ImageBehavior.SetAutoStart(img, true);
        ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(img, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
    }
```

In my view, image figures as:

```
<Image x:Name="img" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: If it's .NET 3.5, an old workaround for some issues was to add x:Name to your Image markup.

Comment: You can also try to experiment, to find a workaround. E.g. display your image in a UserControl, or set the AnimatedSource property on Window.Loaded event or SourceInitialized (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sourceinitialized(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @swiszcz Yes, It's .net 3.5. Also my wpf image already has x:name attribute. Also I have tried name without x: prefix and it does not work.

Comment: @swiszcz Thanks for your last suggestion. I have solved by moving image initialitzation and all the things related to this library to Window_Loaded event. Now it works perfectly! see my update. thx!