# How do i support GIF image in wpf Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, animated-gif

I have grid in wpf. I want to change background of grid with image who support gif image.
I have use following code for set image to the grid :

```
       ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
                    myBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImagePath));                        
                    this.GridName.Background = myBrush;
```

So here how can i change behavior of background for support GIF image;

Comment: Provided that ImagePath is valid, your code should work.

Comment: By _"support gif image"_, do you mean that you want the background to be **animated**?

Comment: Yes @LarsKristensen In image control it is easy to do but for grid back ground how can i do it ?

Comment: @Clemens Image path is valid but gif image not animated that is my concern

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/210922/1136211

Comment: @Clemens i have seen this link in this they use image control. But here i have set image in grid back ground

Comment: Use an Image element that occupies all rows and columns, instead of setting the Background.